# Resizing Nested Elements Proportionately With CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

Suppose I have several `<div>` tags listed on a page vertically. Each tag contains several items like buttons, text, glyphicons, etc.

A need has arisen to implement an expand-collapse button WITHIN each `<div>` tag that would expand-collapse the children of that `<div>` tag. Now, these children are styled similarly and contain similar content. They may be displayed within the parent `<div>` or, perhaps, immediately below it.

My question is how can I resize these children `<div>`s efficiently using CSS? That is, is there a way to set up classes so that I can specify a scale-down factor and have all items within the `div` resize accordingly? OR will I need to resize every DOM and tag separately?

I am also interested in hearing whether it is prudent to display children using the method above. Perhaps I should implement a new page to display children of each `<div>`?

Comment: do the parent `div` elements have a fixed size, or do they expand to fit the content?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow Those div elements are pretty much the entire content on the page. They do have a fixed size that adjusts with the screen size.